# I give the price in google finance sheet get the exact Date in between two dates (Start and End Dates)

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

Summary:
Column H Contains price, C2 and C3 are start and end dates. Check the H2:H price falls in range of Open and Close prices of the day and fetch the date if closing price of the day is above H2.

[In I2 column i want the date on which closing price is closed above the H2 Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcaFv.jpg)

Min and Max functions used to get Min price in two given dates. I want to check the historical data in between two selected dates and fetch the date and price when historical closing price moved above column H, where the custom price values placed by me.

Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2_3KyFWRldPMj0PpTak0tmEPAoEfOQFT9sNj2PhcKs/edit#gid=0

```
=TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE($B$2,"HIGH",C2,C3), 2, 0), 2,1))
```

This gives the High Value in between start and End dates C2,C3 Respectively.

In "H" i have my own price values, when price moves above H2, I want to fetch the date and the value. H2 need not to be matched exactly, Say if H2 is 320, when price opened on a certain day below 320 and closed 321 then i like to get the date and closing price, which falls in between C2 and C3 start and end dates.

Thanks for your help. May your portfolio move like rocket...up...up and up. Thank you.

I am expecting, Fetch the date, When price falls in between the range of value mentioned in H2, for given C2 and C3 start and End dates.

In other words, i have the price in column H, just get the date when the price is in exact match with close price or ABOVE the closing price of the day in between two dates.

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? Tag only the one you use as they are different.